# OR condition in Excel gives always TRUE

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, logic

I have excel with 3 columns:

| User | Status | Task |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mario | done | task 11 |
| Ana | cancelled | task 12 |
| Maria | in work | task 13 |
| Selena | in work | task 14 |
| Mario | done | task 15 |
| Luca | longrunner | task 16 |
| Luca | done | task 17 |
| Selena | in work | task 18 |

I want to have result like this: in first column are people from column A: Mario, Ana, Selena, Luca
In second column, next to the name, are their tasks, but only if the B column is "in work" or "longrunner"

I tried with:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(IF(OR(Sheet1!$B$2:Sheet1!$B$20="longrunner",Sheet1!$B$2:Sheet1!$B$20="in work"),IF(A2=Sheet1!$A$2:Sheet1!$A$20,Sheet1!$C$2:Sheet1!$C$20,""),"")))
```

but first if with OR command don't work well, it give me true all the time.
When I place just one case of column B, without OR

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(IF(Sheet1!$B$2:Sheet1!$B$20="in work",
IF(A2=Sheet1!$A$2:Sheet1!$A$20,Sheet1!$C$2:Sheet1!$C$20,""),"")))
```

it work well.
What to do with first condition?

Comment: Could you actually use some markdown sample data and expected results?

Comment: You need to use + not OR. OR will return one result for the entire array, so if any of them match, you'll get TRUE for all.

Comment: How to use + instead of OR? If I replace OR with +, only get the error in formula

Comment: replace `OR(Test1, Text2)` with `Test1 + Test2` In Excel, `>0 ==TRUE` and `FALSE==0`

Comment: You could try this : `=LET(u,UNIQUE(A2:A9),
HSTACK(u,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(C2:C9,(x=A2:A9)*(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2:B9,{"in work","longrunner"}))),""))))))` this returns blank for `Mario` & `Ana`

Comment: Or, may be this one : `=LET(
a,FILTER(A2:C9,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2:B9,{"in work","longrunner"}))),
b,INDEX(a,,1),
c,INDEX(a,,3),
u,UNIQUE(b),
HSTACK(u,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(c,x=b))))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood correctly you might need to use this:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E10`

```
=LET(
a,FILTER(A2:C9,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2:B9,{"in work","longrunner"}))),
b,INDEX(a,,1),
c,INDEX(a,,3),
u,UNIQUE(b),
HSTACK(u,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(c,x=b))))))
```

---

Or, if you want to have blanks for those don't have `in-work` or `longrunner` then

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=LET(u,UNIQUE(A2:A9),
HSTACK(u,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(C2:C9,(x=A2:A9)*(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2:B9,{"in work","longrunner"}))),""))))))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
= LET(u,UNIQUE(Tabelle1[user]),
t,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,
                              FILTER(Tabelle1[task],(Tabelle1[user]=x)*
                                                                    ((Tabelle1[status]="in work")+(Tabelle1[status]="longrunner")),"-")
                               ))),
HSTACK(u,t))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for quick answer!! The problem is in result. For example, Mario has only status done, but with this solution he has listed 2 tasks: task 11 and task 15 which are not in status "longrunner" or "in work". Ana has only status "canceled", but this solution listed task 12. Luca has only one task with status longrunner, and only that task need to be listed.

Comment: Sorry - Mario / Maria - didn't check correct - but now it works